# Android - Restricting device remotely

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I've been looking into how to restrict access to certain apps, track location, restrict phone calls on an android device and have that dictated remotely. I've come across integrating an Enterprise Mobility Management (EMM) or Mobile Device Management (MDM) solution so I was just wondering if that is the only option here?

Answer (score 0):

Well, Google has its own EMM called [Android Enterprise](https://www.android.com/intl/en-419_us/enterprise/), it offers some features as app restrictions, managed configurations, policies, etc. In backend you can catch all responses from device (ex. GPS). Sometimes if you need a specific feature you will depend from Google's team.

Also, some companies has a [DPC](https://developer.android.com/work/dpc/build-dpc) app (Device Policy Controller), that app can control almost all feature in your device and send a lot of information to MDM or EMM, this app is configured as Device Owner. In this option, you have to develop MDM backend and DPC app as you need them.

Comment: It appears in that DPC documentation that we just have to focus on developing the EMM using the Android Management API which would come with it's own DPC. Appreciate the guidance!